# Problem with Laravel routes - all sub folder traffic ending up in route view

Tags: laravel, routes

Sorry - was difficult to give this one a clear title! But I have an issue and a difference between how my local laravel install is dealing with some routes compared to my live server.

Locally, I have this working:

```
Route::get('/blog', 'BlogController@home');
Route::get('/blog/{post_slug}', 'BlogController@viewPost');
```

As you can probably guess, I want to serve up a list of posts via the home() function if /blog is hit. Then all other traffic with a "slug" after /blog/, I want to load the blog post.

This all works locally.

However on live,

> /blog/my-blog-post

Is serving up the home() function every time.

Where would I start with debugging this. Laravel versions? Server caching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can do this in laravel 5.7+

```
Route::prefix('blog')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', 'BlogController@home');
    Route::get('/{post_slug}', 'BlogController@viewPost');
});
```

before just use: `php artisan optimize`, to clear all cache route and config.

for more info see the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#route-group-prefixes)

Comment: This worked! Thanks for pointing me in the direction if prefixes.